# French " ' " in variable blocks its presentation

Tags: javascript, php, include, character, french

Vague language issue in french.
I am building a website with 5 languages. I have setup language files with among others French which i include using PHP

> $lang['Description'] = 'Photos';
>   $lang['cookie']= "En utilisant notre site Web, vous acceptez que nous utilisions des cookies pour stocker des informations temporaires concernant votre utilisation. Cette information ne sera jamais utilisée à d autres fins!";
>   $lang['regio']='Region';
>   $lang['Viewkalender0'] = "Vous avez une réservation en cours qui doit être traitée avant qu'une réservation ultérieure puisse avoir lieu.";

I ask for these variables with JS
function checkCookie() {

```
var regular=getCookie("Homecheznous-Roullens");
if (regular=="Accepted") {
    document.getElementById('cookie').innerHTML=regular;
} else {
   var x= '<?php echo $lang['cookie'] ?>';
   document.getElementById('cookie').innerHTML=x;
   }
}
```

I can switch between languages without problem, getting the right contents. BUT as soon as I correct the French in "d'autres" only adding the "'" the French contents do not show up. Everything else in the language files still comes up, so the language file is still accepted, and also furtheron in the file I use often the ' without problem. I know about the sensibility of PHP JS and so on on " or ' or vv.That is why you already see that i surrounded this variable with "". It works flawlessly with the variable Viewkalender0 with "qu'une" . ?? Somebody having a clue ?? Cookie is not set BTW. And  as soon as i remove the ',the text shows up.

Have a nice day, Johan

Comment: if you surrond that string `var x= '<?php echo $lang['cookie'] ?>';` with `"` instead of `'` it should work.

Comment: because right now you'll get `var x='...d'autres...';`

Comment: but keep in mind, that any `"` in your strings will break that - unless you escape them with `\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is in your declaration of the variable

```
var x= '<?php echo $lang['cookie'] ?>';
```

so this is replaced server side by for example

```
var x= 'qu'une';
```

so it's normal that  x doesn't get the right text.

**Solition 1 :** 
escape the ' symbole using \

```
qu'une  should be qu\'une
```

**solution 2 :**

try and change

```
var x = "<?php echo $lang['cookie'] ?>";
```

or using escma6

```
var x = `<?php echo $lang['cookie'] ?>`;
```

Comment: Well, I didn't see that one. As always my own fault. And useful hints also. Learned again.